# Values of $6 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt = 2 \sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Let $f$ and $a$ such that $6 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt = 2 \sqrt{x}$.

I need to find the values of $f$ and $a$ that satisfies this condition.

For this i tried:
$F(x) = 6 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt = 2 \sqrt{x}$ then $F´(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ since $ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt = \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ and here i stuck , how can i conclude in get de values of $f$ and **$a$**  please some healp, thanxs for your time.

Comment: yes but the values of a?, i got a function that depends only of x? then a can be arbitrary independent of f(x) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put $x=a$ in $6 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt = 2 \sqrt{x}$. This gives you that
$2\sqrt a=6$ and so $a=9$. Differentiating $6 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt = 2 \sqrt{x}$ we get $\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ which implies that $f(x)=x^{3/2}$. Note that $\int_a^a \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt=0$.

Comment: why can i put $x=a$ and what happen with the integral with this change , $\int_x^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt $ ?

Comment: Well the integral is the 'signed area under the curve'. So if you evaluate from $a$ to $a$ the area (integral) is zero.

Comment: It should be $a=9$, not $x$, right?

Comment: Yes you are right.typo.